# Any Visualforce Data Grid plugins?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

Any recommendations on grids that are richer than standard HTML tables?I need a data grid to list sObject rows and attribute columnd on a VF page under a Salesforce tab.

The attributes are a mix of string dates, URLs. On each row I want CRUD buttons to edit or delete records. Built in column sorting, filtering etc.

I've previously used WiceGrid for RoR and looking for anything equivalent for VF - https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid

Answer (score 9):

While this is a javascript grid implementation as opposed to a visualforce one, I cannot speak highly enough about [Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid).  It is flexible so you will be able to add buttons in each row and also extremely performant, capable of handling even hundreds of thousands of records.

It has the built-in column sorting and filtering you are looking for, in addition to many other features.  Here is an example of slickgrid doing both of those things: http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html

I have used slickgrid successfully many times and getting data into it can be as simple as hooking up a javascript remoting call that just returns query results on the apex side.

Comment: are you aware of any good tutorials detailing how to implement SlickGrid into a VF page?

Answer (score 8):

Its not quite a feature rich as some of your other options but we use a component called PageBlockTableEnhancer

https://github.com/Avinava/Visualforce-PageBlock-Table-Enhancer

The nicest thing we have found about it is that its super simple to setup just include the component on your page with a regular pageBlockTable and it adds pagination, column sorting, etc...

like this:

```
<c:PageBlockTableEnhancer targetPbTableIds="apps" paginate="true" defaultPageSize="100" pageSizeOptions="5,10,20,30,40,50,100"/>  

<apex:pageBlock title="{!grantRound.Name} Completed Applications">   
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!applications}" var="a" id="apps"> 
<apex:column value="{!a.Title__c}"/> 
...
```

Comment: Its really nice to see people are actually using it. Probably github is not updated with the latest code. I will try to update the same. Anyways I did another one here By the way I did another one http://blogforce9.blogspot.in/2013/11/pageblocktableenhanceradv-yet-another.html .

Answer (score 4):

I just made my configurable **[Visualforce TableGrid](https://github.com/Up2Go/visualforce-table-grid)** component open source on Github.

It features:

- Native Salesforce.com Look And Feel
- Works as Standalone table grid or as an embedded replacement for Related List
- Works as replacement for Standard Lookup popups with
- Works for Standard and Custom SObjects
- Spreadsheet-like Cell-Editing
- Delete Muliple records
- Pagination with cutomizable page size
- Filter Builder UI to let users filter records
- Field Selection UI to let users customize columns
- Each user`s customizations can be auto-saved in a "database-cookie"

Feel free to use, share and improve ;-)

Comment: Corrected the URL to Github!

Comment: Robert, I am having a hard time installing the Visualforce TableGrid component. I grabbed the code and tools but dont know how to integrate. Do you have instructions that are more detailed than the README please?

Comment: @CorrieSigler Moved your answer to a comment, I know you couldn't do that because you're new to the site! Welcome :)

Comment: @CorrieSigler: Please open a Github issue for questions related to tablegrid.

Answer (score 1):

I also found a [grid solution](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Making_A_Spreadsheet_On_Force.com) on the Developer Force Wiki that uses **ParamQuery** with JavaScript remoting. The page is titled, "Building Spreadsheets with Visualforce and Apex".

P.S. Thanks for starting this thread, as I'm about to dive into a project that requires a similar grid.